# Cannot append to dynamically generated content

Tags: jquery, html

When I load the page the #navbarUsername remains empty. all other scripts below this run correctly. 
I have also tried $(document).on('ready', '#navbarUsername', function () {...
and it did not work.

**JS:**

```
$('#navbar-placeholder').load("navbar.html");
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#navbar-placeholder').on('ready', function () {
        $('#navbarUsername').append(UserInfo.Name + " " + UserInfo.Surname + "(" + UserInfo.UserUsername + ")");
    });

});
```

**HMTL:**

```
<div id="navbar-placeholder"></div>
```

**and navbar.html which is loaded:**

```
<nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="navbarUsername"></a><----HERE--->
                </li>
                <li class="navbar-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" style="cursor:pointer;" id="logout" >Log Out</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: From where do you get `UserInfo`?

Comment: "ready" will run when the main DOM is ready, no matter what selector you specify - see https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) inside `document-ready` handler and use [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) complete callback handler to append `UserInfo`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#navbar-placeholder').load("navbar.html", function () {
        $('#navbarUsername').append(UserInfo.Name + " " + UserInfo.Surname + "(" + UserInfo.UserUsername + ")");
    });
});
```